# Rule to transform my path to an entire query

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string, url-encoding

#### Example :

I go in the browser at :

> www.example.com/**documents/pages/doc.php?bacon=baked&this=tastes_good**

And I would like that this link access to this page with the path encoded into the query :

> www.example.com/index.php?url=**documents%2Fpages%2Fdoc.php%3Fbacon%3Dbaked%26this%3Dtastes_good**

The thing is that this index.php will need to take the big "url" query variable to decode and modify it in PHP and then fopen() the wanted page from an other site.
I need to do all that because the two sites need to use the same $_SESSION, databases and files and it would be harder to completely separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1%3F%1 [B,NE,L]
```

You may have to enable [AllowEncodedSlashes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) in your server's `httpd.conf` configuration file if you still find those `/`s not getting encoded to `%2F`.

Comment: There are already some lines in my .htaccess, if I just add this to the end, will it be okay or it could interfere with what is already in place ? What is already there contains some Rewritecond and finish with an [L] at the end, I don't know what it does or if these conditions could enlarge to these new lines..?

Comment: Just copy my last two lines and paste below other existing rules. That way it won't break anything.

Comment: I tested on : [http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it will output [http://www.example.com/index.php](http://www.example.com/index.php), it doesn't seems to work. It may be because of the "?" character needing to be escaped.

Comment: That site does not support all % variables like %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} etc.

Comment: It almost works, but when I echo the actual URL and QUERY it looks like : index.php?url=index.phpFurl=documents/pages/doc.phpFbacon=baked&this=tastes_good

Comment: Okay I edited it a bit and now I don't know why it does that but it loops infinitely, like:   "**test/index.php?url=index.phpFurl=index.phpFurl=index.phpFurl=index.phpFu........**"  
the lines looks like that:
**"RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test\/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^test\/(.*)$ test\/index.php?url=$1%3F%{QUERY_STRING} [R]"**  
what is wrong ?

Comment: Can you try with `index.php?url=$1?%{QUERY_STRING}` i.e. ? in place of %3F? Please, switch back the rules or you risk messing up your file.

Comment: now it looks like: **/index.php?url=index.php?url=documents/pages/doc.php?bacon=baked&this=tastes_good** and my .htaccess's end looks like: **RewriteBase /** (new line)
**RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]**

Comment: I think you missed reading my comment. I had asked to copy last two lines. That doesn't include `RewriteBase`. Only copy `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` and add them together.

Comment: I tried a lot of ways and tried to switch some lines just to see if it could had worked even if there was previous lines.. So, now it looks like: **/index.php?url=documents/pages/doc.php?bacon=baked&this=tastes_good** with the two last lines and the "%3F" replaced by "?". The url is not perfect, but if it stays withing the server and never get seen I can manipulate it and replace things to make it fit better... But I would like the link to be more normal, and without a loop of the "?url="

Comment: Are you still getting into a loop? Could you explain what you meant by "normal"? What's wrong with the URL?

Comment: I'm not still getting into a loop, but right now the URL should be like **index.php?url=documents%2Fpages%2Fdoc.php%3Fbacon%3Dbaked%26this%3Dtastes_good** or at least like **index.php?url=documents/pages/doc.php%3Fbacon=baked%26this=tastes_good** instead of **/index.php?url=documents/pages/doc.php?bacon=baked&this=tastes_good**

Comment: Ah, that's good news. I was wondering why would you be still running into the loop. Now, that's been taken care of rest is easy. Just add `[B]` to the rule. Check my update.